# multiple constructors in java

Tags: java, arguments

```
class Objectsmultiplecnstrctrs {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ObjectsForMultipleConstructors engg2=new ObjectsForMultipleConstructors(1);
        ObjectsForMultipleConstructors engg3=new ObjectsForMultipleConstructors(1,2);
        ObjectsForMultipleConstructors engg=new ObjectsForMultipleConstructors(1,2,3);

    }
}

// secondary class


public class ObjectsForMultipleConstructors {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;


    public ObjectsForMultipleConstructors(int h){
        this.hour=h;
        System.out.printf("give one ",+hour);

    }

    public ObjectsForMultipleConstructors(int h,int m){
        System.out.printf("goddamn ",+m);
    }

    public ObjectsForMultipleConstructors(int h,int m,int s){
        System.out.println("guess");

    }
}
```

OUTPUT is give one goddamn guess

Now the thing is i have declared int hour =h and value of h I assigned in the arguments in the main class,so im expecting the value of h which i defined to be displayed next to the text (System.out.printf("goddamn ",+m);) ,,but its doing what i want it to do ,where im missing

Comment: I assume you mean *not* 'doing what I want', but you haven't specified that in enough detail. What are you getting instead? Compile error? Exception? Unexpected output? At the moment there is no question here.

Comment: Unless you show your main method, no-one will be able to guess what you're talking about.

Comment: @Himanshu Saxena Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

Why you use comma System.out.printf("give one "`,`+hour);  ?

it must be System.out.printf("give one " + hour);

the description of printf usage is :

A convenience method to write a formatted string to this 
 output stream using the specified format string and 
 arguments. 
An invocation of this method of the form out.printf(format, 
 args) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation 
     out.format(format, args) 
Parameters:
    format A format string as described in Format string 
     syntax
    args Arguments referenced by the format specifiers in 
     the format string. If there are more arguments than format 
     specifiers, the extra arguments are ignored. The number of 
     arguments is variable and may be zero. The maximum 
     number of arguments is limited by the maximum dimension 
     of a Java array as defined by the Java Virtual Machine 
     Specification. The behaviour on a null argument depends on 
     the conversion.

Comment: I think he's mixing `System.out.print` with `System.out.printf`. So, it should probably be either `System.out.print("give one " + hour);` or `System.out.printf("give one %d", hour);`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to format and print arguments to `printf()` you need to specify them in the pattern string, like:

```
System.out.printf("give one %d ", hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a format specifier as well in a printf statement

```
System.out.printf("give one %d ",hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you have not used **%d** access specifier in the method **printf**